# Retrieve list of objects records and display them in a VF picklist

Tags: apex, visualforce, picklist, record-type

I got a object called BUnit__c, this object has two record types (BUnit and Project).

There's another object called Project_Portfolio__c which has a lookup field called 'BU_Project__c' to the above BUnit__c object.(Child Relationship name is Project_Portfolios).

I want to get all Project_Portfolio__c records which are of 'Project' record type, and display those records in a picklist in the VF page.

How can I do this ?

Also I want to add 'All' and 'None' words to the same picklist with the Project_Portfolio__c records as well.

Any help on this is appreciated !!!

```
public void portfolioProjectRecords(Id currentBUnitId){
        String strSelected;
        strSelected = '';
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

        for(Project_Portfolio__c obj :[SELECT Id, Name, BU_Project__r.ProjectType__c FROM Project_Portfolio__c WHERE BU_Project__c =: currentBUnitId AND BU_Project__r.ProjectType__c = 'Project'] ){
        options.add(new SelectOption(obj.Id,obj.Name));
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you tried? what you have tried till now add the codes above comment then we can help you out.

Comment: Apologies! I updated my answer modifying with your code and it saves. I need to add more functionality to test this works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VF page

```
<apex:page controller="sampleCon">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:selectList value="{!strSelected}" multiselect="false" size="1">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!options}"/>
        </apex:selectList>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Apex Class

```
public class sampleCon {
 public String strSelected  {get;set;}
 public List<SelectOption> options {get;set;}
 public sampleCon()
 {
    strSelected = '';
    options = new List<SelectOption>();
    for(Project_Portfolio__c obj :[SELECT Id, Name FROM Project_Portfolio__c WHERE BU_Project__c =: 'BU_Project__c.Id'] )//instead of BU_Project__c.Id pass actual id
    {
        options.add(new SelectOption(obj.Id,obj.Name));
    }
 }
}
```

try with this.